# Makers google maps javascript. O que está errado?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Estou criando um script para adicionar os valores de um vetor em um mapa (somente as posições 0 e 1), porem nada acontece. no console não há erros.

Script:

```
function marcar(){         
  var marcacao = function(position){

    // Gravar dados da posição capturada em uma variável...
    var coords = position.coords;

    var pontos = [
      [-30.403.601, -56.744.400,  queimada],
      [-30.403.601, -56.744.400,  queimada],
      [-30.403.601, -56.744.400,  queimada],
      [-30.403.601, -56.744.400,  queimada],
      [33.475.201,  -98.228.699,  queimada],
      [32.294.300,  -97.525.497,  queimada],
      [32.294.300,  -97.525.497,  queimada],
      [32.294.300,  -97.525.497,  lixo urbano],
      [35.789.001,  -109.478.699, raios],
      [28.040.701,  -83.462.997,  falta de agua],
      [28.040.701,  -83.462.997,  falta de agua],
      [33.176.102,  -122.465.401, queimada],
      [-22.569.380, -44.964.485,  queimada],
      [33.176.102,  -122.465.401, raios],
      [21.985.701,  -95.394.997,  queimada],
      [21.985.701,  -95.394.997,  falta de agua],
      [20.675.800,  -109.457.497, raios],
      [20.675.800,  -109.457.497, queimada]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i<pontos.length; i++){
      var ponto = pontos[i];    
      // GOOGLE MAPS: Mostrar marcador no mapa...
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), 
        { 
          center : new google.maps.LatLng( ponto[0], ponto[1] ), 
          zoom : 5, 
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        }
      );
      var image = 'images/ray001.png';
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
          title : "VOCÊ ESTÁ AQUI: "+ponto[0]+", "+ponto[1],
          position : new google.maps.LatLng(ponto[0], ponto[1]),
          map: map,
          icon: image
        });
      marker.setMap(map);
    }
  }

  // Caso falhe na captura, faça isso...
  var fnFalhar = function(error){
    navigator.notification.alert("Erro ao capturar posição: "+error.message, "INFORMAÇÃO");
  }

  // Opções para acessar o GPS...
  var opcoes = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

  // CAPTURAR POSIÇÃO: Chamada a API de Geolocalização (GPS) via Apache Cordova
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(marcacao, fnFalhar, opcoes);
}
marcar();
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiz um teste com seu código e o mesmo apresentou problemas na declaração dos valores do array, exceto isso, funcionou perfeitamente.
Segue um exemplo de como você deve declarar os valores.

```
var pontos = [
  [-30.403601, -56.744400,  'queimada']
];
```

Em sua declaração, `[-30.403.601, -56.744.400,  queimada]`, o JavaScript não identifica `-30.403.601` como um valor número e `queimada` como uma string.